# How is console.log used for debugging?

Tags: debugging

I previously researched the definition of console.log, everyone seems to be saying it's used to debug. I'm a novice programmer, I can see that the console.log prints whatever is passed to it, such as a string or number. So can you explain how the console.log is used for debugging?

Comment: What are you even asking about?  What development environment?

Comment: This is a "code" QA site. Make your question as specific as possible. Add info to eliminate ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

debugging is the process of removing the "bugs" or issues that is causing unexpected results to your program.
for example,
in a function

```
function fed(){
    a = 3;
    b = 1;

    console.log( b );

    c = b + 3
}
fed();
```

console.log() is used to take a "peek" into the value of b at the execution at that particular line.

You may also find the **debugger;** useful as it will stop on that particular line of your code.

```
function fed(){
    a = 3;
    b = 1;

    console.log( b );

    c = b + 3;
    debugger;  //<-will stop at this line
}
fed();
```

try these in your HTML/javascript file. What do you thin will the b contain? Check your "console logs" to find out

This page is also a helpful and can shed a light to your research :)
http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners

Answer (score 0):

it helps to understand what value a variable has at a given time. This method is generally used, when a complete debugger (with breakpoints and stack analysis) is not of any help.

So by printing out a variable of interest at a point of interest, one may get the answers one seeks.